# "Enter your password for "x" in Internet Accounts." after recent two upgrades

Tags: macos, upgrade

I just finished the upgrade from macOS 11.5.2 to 11.6. After logging back in, I see a notification titled

> GOOGLE PASSWORD REQUIRED

with the text

> Enter your password for "x" in Internet Accounts.

for my two accounts.

This has happened for only the most recent two upgrades of this MacBook Pro. I have upgraded macOS more times than I can remember since my first in 2008 and until recently it has never acted this way.

1. Has Apple changed some policy resulting in those passwords being
   removed?
2. What can I do to cause the passwords to be maintained
   across upgrades? This is the question that must be answered.

I ask because I see no good reason why I should have to enter the passwords after an upgrade. I even contemplated the possibility that the removal of the passwords might make the system more secure, but I've decided such a policy is only kicking the can down the road.

When I went to `System Preferences -> Internet Accounts`, I clicked one of the two accounts and it said I had to open Chrome to enter the passwords. For both of them, I had to type in the passwords and for one of the accounts I had to open gmail on my phone. One is my work account and the other is my personal account.

Near the end of my none too helpful chat with apple support I realized I should see what happens after a simple normal reboot. Afterward, I was not notified that I should enter the passwords. That doesn't prove a whole lot because I could get notified if I reboot in, say, one week (i.e., the passwords might expire). I was hoping that I *would* get notified so that I could more easily reproduce the problem. Obviously, it would be problematic to attempt to use `Time Machine` to go backwards in time and then upgrade again.

Comment: Can confirm exactly that for an update from 11.6.1 to 11.6.2